# Syntax Highlighting

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Is it possible to enable syntax highlighting for **most popular scripting languages** in this context (python, lua, javascript) **and bash** for a faster understanding? In addition it would be nice to highlight **ffmpeg arguments**, but I don't know if this is possible at all...

---

### Yeah, it's enabled!

Based on this post: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) we have to explicitly override the highlighting via html comment like:

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here
```

#### python

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->
```

```py
while True:
    n = raw_input("Please enter 'hello':")
    if n.strip() == 'hello':
        break
```

#### javascript

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
```

```js
var a = 3;
while( !(a < 0)){
    alert("hello");
    a--;
}
```

#### lua

```
<!-- language: lang-lua -->
```

```lua
local i = 1
while a[i] do
  print(a[i])
  i = i + 1
end
```

#### bash

```
<!-- language: lang-bash -->
```

```bash
ext=mp4
for f in /some/dir/*.$ext; do
    new=${f/%.$ext/-rotated.$ext};
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf transpose=2 -c:a copy -metadata:s:v rotate="" "$new"
done
```

Comment: Maybe we can come up with with the list of what needs to be added

Comment: @Volodya Sounds great! My list is almost complete, but I could add more detail to scripting languages... I'm not an ffmpeg expert - could you please write the ffmpeg part? I will add it to my question, of course... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

Mods will still need to enable this on a per-tag basis, and I'm not *completely* certain that ffmpeg works as well as we'd like, but it has been enabled on the main site and meta.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks Tim! Here you can find an example question with python, bash and ffmpeg: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15390/best-way-to-batch-rotate-3000-h-264-videos/15405 No highlighting at the moment, what else we have to do to see it visually? Thanks again.

Comment: Based on this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work python works perfects with `<!-- language: lang-py -->`, but `<!-- language: tag-ffmpeg -->` don't work for ffmpeg, see: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15390/best-way-to-batch-rotate-3000-h-264-videos/15405. What we have to do in this case? Thanks Tim!

Comment: avidemux doesn't even have a tag. so i guess it won't work. see http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13479/how-do-i-convert-a-series-of-pngs-into-an-avi-using-avidemux

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, however it requires a CM to turn it on.

Comment: CM means Community Manager, ie a Stack Exchange employee.

Answer (score 1):

Per discussion in the comments, here's my list of tools that should have their options added:

- avconv
- avidemux_cli
- ffmpeg
- ffmpeg2theora
- mkvmerge
- oggz-tools
- transcode

I can help with full listing for `avconv`, `oggz`, and `ffmpeg2theora`. I can also do some basic things with `ffmpeg` (but i try to stay away from that community, so if somebody else wants to take over that job i'll be more than happy). Other tools i have used sufficiently to be able to generate a list looking at man pages where necessary.

What format should the options be in? Are we looking for a list of every potential option or do we need information about their potential order/interaction as well?

Comment: It's a flavour of Javascript, but After Effects expressions could be added to this list. There are unique expressions things like thisComp that would benefit from some syntax highlighting.